# Wordpress: force wp_tag_cloud to display empty categories?

Tags: wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

I'm using `wp_tag_cloud()` to display the categories in my custom taxonomy:

```
$args = array
(
    'format'                    => 'list',
    'orderby'                   => 'name', 
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
    'link'                      => 'view', 
    'taxonomy'                  => 'my_tax', 
    'echo'                      => true 
);
    
wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

The problem is that only categories with posts are displayed, so instead of seeing 40+ categories I only see 3.

**Is there a way to force wp_tag_cloud to display all categories?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some spelunking in `wp_tag_cloud()` (line 526 in wp-includes/category-template.php) shows that it calls [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) (line 1114 in wp-includes/taxonomy.php) and passes through the $args array that was passed to `wp_tag_cloud()`. `get_terms()` has a param called `hide_empty` that defaults to `true`.

This is untested, but I think if you simply add `"hide_empty" => false"` to your $args you'll get what you want. There may be other args to `get_terms()` that are of interest to you.

Comment: +1 for spelunking as much as actually just checking out the Codex page you link to. Cardinal rule of WordPress I've learned after too much pain and too many hours trying to figure some things out: "the Codex has the answer(s)".

Comment: @stealthyninja: Except in this case the `wp_tag_cloud()` page makes no mention of `get_terms()`. It does mention `get_tags()` which calls `get_terms()`, but only in a tangential way. The two routines are not the same since `get_tags()` is hardwired to just return `post_tags`.